# Reason for the diferentiability of function on open interval in Rolle's Theorem

Tags: calculus

"Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $]a,b[$ ,further let $f(a)=f(b)$. Then there exist at least one number $c \in ]a,b[$ such that $f'(c)=0$". The above statement is the *Rolle's Theorem*. Why we take open interval for differentiability rather then close interval. What's the reason behind it??

Comment: It suffices. There's no reason to impose more stringent conditions.

Answer (score 2):

See the proof of the theorem. If $f$ isn't constant, the point where $f$ reaches the max or the min $\in(a,b)$, so is a local extremum...

Answer (score 0):

The requirement of differentiability over the whole closed interval would be excessive. Recall how the proof works: it shows that derivative vanishes somewhere in the interior part of the domain because there is at least a local maximum or minimum. Do you really need differentiability at extreme points for this?

Try to answer the last question while looking at the following graph: 
[image: A function satisfying the assumption of Rolle's theorem while not being differentiable on the boundary of its domain]

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
\sqrt{x}, & 0\le x < \frac{1}{2} \\
-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(x-1)^2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{8}, & \frac{1}{2}\le x < \frac{3}{2} \\
\sqrt{2-x}, & \frac{3}{2}\le x \le 2.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Do you agree that the function shown has a maximum? However, is it differentiable at extreme points?

Answer (score -1):

Simply put: there is no two-side derivative for the bounders of the closed interval. only one side derivative exists for $a$ and $b$. so we must exclude the two points.

Comment: I disagree with this answer. That's not the point: we could require that the one-side derivatives exist. The OP asks why we do not require this.