# Why Rolle's theorem considers differentiability on open $(a,b)$ rather than closed $[a,b]$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

This question is a duplicate,but still I'm posting it because the answers given in the previously asked questions(by other users) are not satisfactory and since my reputation in the website isn't high enough, yet, I couldn't post any comments in the previous questions to get doubts clarified.

So, why is it defined in open $(a,b)$ rather than closed $[a,b]$.

Could you explain with an example?

Note: preiously asked questions(whose answers are not satisfactory) are:

[Continuous and differentiable function in Rolle's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2671989/continuous-and-differentiable-function-in-rolles-theorem)

[Reason for the diferentiability of function on open interval in Rolle's Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/745185/reason-for-the-diferentiability-of-function-on-open-interval-in-rolles-theorem)

Comment: It's because it's not necessary and it makes for a stronger theorem. For instance, consider something like $f(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ on $[-1,1]$. This is not differentiable at the endpoints, yet still satisfies the hypotheses for Rolle's theorem.

Comment: Which question is it a duplicate of?  What precisely is it you don't understand about the answer?

Comment: @SaucyO'Path ,I meant, the previously asked questions by other users

Comment: Now we know _what_ questions had unsatisfactory answers, but not _why_ or _how_ the answers were unsatisfactory. Some of the answers give examples; what was wrong with them?

Answer (score 2):

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ a continuous function, which is differentiable on $(a,b)$. If $f(a)=f(b)$, then Rolle's theorem says: there is $s \in (a,b)$ such that $f'(s)=0$.

Look at a proof of this theorem, then you will see:

1. you need that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$

and

2. you  only(!) need that $f$ is differentiable  on $(a,b)$.

Comment: I have checked the proof on wikipedia ,which part of the derivation of the theorem,imply the conditions mentioned above{f is continuous in [a,b] and differentiable in (a,b)} or I mean where does it show that the above conditions are necessary for c to exist in (a,b).

Comment: @Banchin It is _not_ necessary for the "continuous" and "differentiable" conditions to hold in order for $c$ to exist. You can easily make a function for which $f'(c)=0$ for some $c \in [a,b]$ and yet one or both of the mentioned conditions are violated. The theorem is "this result holds If these conditions hold," not "this result holds if _and only if_ these conditions hold."

Answer (score 1):

> A function is called differentiable if it is differentiable at each point in its domain.

You basically want to talk about function being differentiable at every point in the domain...

You can not talk about a function being differentiable at a point which is not an interior point...

If your function is $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ then you have to say about differentiability of $f$ at $a$ but as that notion is not there, you just ignore $a$ (as well as $b$) and considered $f:(a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

In the new domain $(a,b)$, every point is interior point, so you can say function is differentiable on $(a,b)$.

Comment: Does this make some sense??

Comment: Couldn't  a function have at least  a one sided derivative at a domain endpoint? [As Fred's answer notes, Rolle's doesn't need endpoint differentiability anyway, but in  a way your third line isn't quite right.]

Comment: You wrote: "You can not talk about a function being differentiable at a point which is not an interior point... ". This is not true ! If $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is a function, you can investigate the existence of the limit $ \lim_{x \to a+}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$.

Comment: @coffeemath it may be your convention but for me derivative is two sided...

Comment: @Fred : Okay! what do you do after investigating one sided limit?? it may be your convention but for me derivative is two sided...

Comment: I've seen one sided derivatives in *many* analysis/calc texts. It's not "my convention" but instead fairly widely used.